# alias not showing up in bash history

Tags: linux, bash, alias

HISTIGNORE variable is set to:

```
export HISTIGNORE="&:ls*:reboot:pwd:exit:clear:[ \t]*"
```

I have couple of Alias set. One of them is

```
alias todo='emacs ~/Dropbox/Documents/todo.txt'
```

None of them shows up in history. Not that I want them to show up in history, but what baffles me is, why the hell they do not show up in history.

Comment: So if you were to do just `emacs ~/Dropbox/Documents/todo.txt` - that shows up in your history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash, the sequence `\t` only means tab inside of `$'...'`.  That's why your pattern matches your `todo` command; it matches anything that starts with `t`.

You can fix it like this:

```
tab=$'\t'
export HISTIGNORE="&:ls*:reboot:pwd:exit:clear:[ $tab]*"
unset tab
```